# Parse JSON values from curl command in node.js

Tags: json, node.js, curl

I'm able to get a stream of JSON from Twitter onto the client with this code:

```
var command = 'curl -d @tracking https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json -uUsername:Password'

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

  child = exec(command);

  child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {

  res.write(data);

  });

}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
```

but I can't get 'text' or 'id' value's from the JSON.  I've tried using jQuery's parsJSON(), and other things such as code like this:

```
var command = 'curl -d @tracking https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json -uUsername:password'

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

  child = exec(command);

  child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {

  for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    reduceJSON = data[i]["text"]
    stringJSON = String(reduceJSON)
    res.write(stringJSON);
}

});

}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
```

I keep getting streams of 'undefined' or 'readyStatesetRequestHeadergetAllResponseHeadersgetResponseHeader' or 'object:object'.  Anyone know how to get individual values?

Comment: Why are you using CURL and exec instead of node request libraries?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that `data` is a string, not JSON. You need to buffer all of the data until `child` emits 'end'. After end has run, you need to use `JSON.parse` to convert the data into a JavaScript object.

That said, using a while separate cURL process makes no sense here. I would use the `request` module, and do something like this:

```
var request = require('request');
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

  var r = request.post(
    'https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json',
    { auth: "Username:Password", 'body': "track=1,2,3,4" },
    function(err, response, body) {
      var values = JSON.parse(body);

      console.log(values);

    }
  );
  r.end();
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
```

Let me know if that doesn't quite work. I obviously don't have a user or password, so I can't test it.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It outputs that request has no method 'end'.  Perhaps because the response is a continuous stream?  When I remove .end() I get a successful response but the first curly brace throws an error i.e. `{"retweet_count":0,"favorited":false,"text":"Cumbrian pubs could cash in on Sk
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`   So I'll probably just use a third party but that's not conducive to learning Node.

Comment: That `end` bit was a typo. I'm still not 100% sure you need it, but try what I have now. As for the parse, print out `body` and see if it is all valid JSON.